# Assigning Values to a 2d array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I am trying to assign values from a db to a 2d array, but its only showing the last iterms.

Here is the code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
$MyData = array( array("Focus Area", $row["FocusArea"]),
               array("Finding Title", $row["FindingTitle"]),
               array("Finding Detail", $row["FindindDetail"]) 
             ); 

}//End While
```

What am I doing wrong please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$MyData[] = $row;
```

would be enough

I'd also suggest to make a function, as getting an array from db is a very common routine.
So, you'll be able to get your data in one line,

```
$myData = getRows("SELECT * FROM table");
```

Comment: aah @Col. i see you after such a long time :), +1 for recommending a better solution. the only thing i don't like about the query is you have made use of `*` which is considered to be the bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a new array each time the loop runs. Declare it out of the while loop, and add the new values.

```
$MyData = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
$MyData[] = array( array("Focus Area", $row["FocusArea"]),
               array("Finding Title", $row["FindingTitle"]),
               array("Finding Detail", $row["FindindDetail"]) 
             ); 

}//End While
```

Comment: The `.` in `$MyData[] .= ` is used for string concatenation, so it is wrong to use here (array will be turned into a string...)

Comment: you should not be using `.=` for an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myData = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
$MyData[] = array( array("Focus Area", $row["FocusArea"]),
               array("Finding Title", $row["FindingTitle"]),
               array("Finding Detail", $row["FindindDetail"]) 
             ); 

}//End While
```

this will do the trick

Comment: it is always better to declare the data type you are going to use. so initially it should be `$myData = array()` instead of just declaring it.